# Sorting Items by Multiple Criteria

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I am writing a program that takes a list of soccer games played, and outputs the standings in the league from that. I'm done most of the parsing work, but am struggling with the sort.

The sorting criteria are as follows:
A) Team with most points.
B) Team with fewest games played.
C) Team with most wins.
D) Team with highest goal differential. 
E) Team with most goals scored.
F) Alphabetical order.

My code gives me a dictionary created from all the games input, in the form below:

```
{'Cagliari': [3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1], 'Torino': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, -1, 1], 
'Lazio': [3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 1], 'AC Milan': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
'Napoli': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, -2, 1], 'Inter Milan': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
```

Where each key:value pair is in a certain pattern:

```
'Team' : [points, wins, ties, losses, goals for, goals against, goal differential, 
games played]
```

My question is, how do I sort based on these multiple criteria?

Comment: [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> teams = {'Cagliari': [3, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1], 'Torino': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, -1, 1], 
... 'Lazio': [3, 1, 0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 1], 'AC Milan': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
... 'Napoli': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, -2, 1], 'Inter Milan': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
>>> sorted(teams, key=lambda t : (teams[t][0], teams[t][-1]*-1, teams[t][1], teams[t][-2], teams[t][4], t))
['Napoli', 'Torino', 'AC Milan', 'Inter Milan', 'Cagliari', 'Lazio']
```

Comment: The alphabetical tiebreak doesn't seem to work, but if I can find a way to understand this type of sort I'm sure I can fix it.

Comment: @idalsin: the tuple in `lambda` expression, put all your criteria in it. More important criteria ge to the left of less important criteria. Also, if you want to sort by some criterion in descending order, multiply it by `-1`